# PHP space function similar to ASP space()

Tags: php

Is there a function that will print a spceified number of spaces in PHP?

Here is the ASP equivelant example:

```
Dim txt
 txt=Space(10)
 document.write(txt)

Output:

"          "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `str_repeat` is the thing you want.

[str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)

```
<?php
echo str_repeat("x", 10);
?>
```

will output

```
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

To get spaced use

```
echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 10);
```